# Parent component getting re-initialised when navigating to child component

Tags: angular, router, router-outlet

Please help me.
I have problem with second router for children
My routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login'},
  {
    path: 'web', component: WebComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
      {path: 'skills', component: SkillsComponent},
    ]
  }
]
```

AboutComponent is without module.
In WebComponent I have button:

```
<nav>
    <button [routerLink]="'/web/about'" (click)="clickButton()" [ngClass]="{animationStart: anim > 4}">About me</button>
</nav>
<div class="root">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

When I click this button, I have some problem. The ngOnInit in WebComponent restart. Why? I don't want this, because also the animation is running again.
Please help me.

GitHub: https://github.com/ZakuroPL/webCV/tree/main/src/app

Comment: what does `clickButton()` method do?

Comment: clickButton(){
    if(this.isZakuro){
      this.isZakuro = false;
    } it's only for disactive ngClass

Comment: Your routing looks good. Just change the routerLink property binding like `[routerLink]="['about']"` . If this doesn't solves the issue, there is definitely something else triggering the WebComponent in your code.

Comment: Could you check my whole code? Thanks https://github.com/ZakuroPL/webCV/tree/main/src/app

Comment: Finally, after going through your code, I figured out the mistake. You are defining the web path in two modules (app and web). Move it inside web module and the component should not re-initialise.

Comment: You are awesome and helpful. I'm grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why is it refreshing whole web component, but what I know, if you have children routes, you don't have to call them like `[routerLink]="'/web/about'"`, it would be enough to use `about` only
and normally, you should provide to router link an array, so maybe that is actually refreshing your page

Try it like this `[routerLink]="['about']"` and see what is going to happen

Comment: Thanks, your code also work, but still refreshing and after click button i still got console.log from webComponent again.